# Python create object and access class method at the same time

Tags: python, object

The object is created by `a = Foo()`, the object can be nested with `a.b`, after that I can perform `a.b.bar()` to `print("Hello World")`

```
class Foo:
    def bar():
        print("Hello World")
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        setattr(self,name,Foo)
```

The problem is I need to first use `a.b` to create an object first, then only I can do `a.b.bar()`, is there a way that I could do `a.b.bar()` straightaway to create the object and access the `bar()` at the same time?

Comment: `return` something from `__getattr__`…!?

Comment: As the name implies, `__getattr__` should `return` a value…! It's unusual and perhaps not advisable to use `__getattr__` to *set* new attributes, but okay, this may make sense in some cases. But the method should still *`return`* a value. So… `return` the value you're setting…

Comment: @deceze Hey, thanks for the ans, it worked but now I am adding an if statement inside the __getattr__. example="b", adding if name ==example: return self.name won't work

Comment: Uhm… `value = Foo; setattr(self, name, value); return value`…

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the answer again! Do you know where can I find examples/ pointers about these magic methods overwrite or anything related to get to know more by myself?

Comment:  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names